# How to insert a column value by comparing columns from two data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns from two different dataframes and insert a new column in second dataframe from the first one.

I have two data frames df1 and df2. I would like to compare ID column from df1 and df2 and insert filename in df2 .

```
df1:

ID   Date         filename          col2
1    20220207     data1.csv         AAA
2    20220207     data2.csv         BBB
3    20220207     data2.csv         CCC


df2:
ID  Date        col1
1   20220207    123XER
2   20220207    234FGY
3   20220207    000GGG

Result
df2:
ID  Date        col1       filename
1   20220207    123XER     data1.csv 
2   20220207    234FGY     data2.csv 
3   20220207    000GGG     data2.csv
```

I tried with below code

```
df2['FileName']=np.where(df1['ID'].equals(df2['ID']), df1['filename'], '')
```

It throws below error.

```
Length of values (1863) does not match length of index (1862)
```

Can anyone please help me with this logic?

Comment: considered merging? df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='ID', how='left')

Comment: but I just want one column filename. the table has many columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
df2['FileName'] = np.where(df1['ID'] == df2['ID'], df1['filename'], None)
```